# How do I identify this square light fitting so I can replace the globe

Tags: lighting

I'd like to know of this light fitting is a standard type of light fitting (and if so, what is it called), and whether or not I'd be likely to find an existing globe / cover that mounts over the fitting. In case it's relevant to identify the fitting, I'm in Australia.

The bracket is a square piece of metal that hangs out from the wall, with the outer edges of the square measuring 20cmx20cm and the inner edges measuring 16cmx16cm with two small notches in the bottom edge.

[image: Picture of mounting bracket]

Comment: That **is** a light fitting - what you are looking for is a replacement "globe" (non-globular in this case, presumably.) try "replacement globes for light fixtures" in your favorite search engine.

Comment: Thanks, I've re-worded my question based on your advice :)

Comment: Since you measure in cm I'd also put my location down. Most users here are from the US, but also Canada and some from everywhere else. This would be good to know before folks start throwing advice to you.

Comment: Added a note to say that I'm in Australia.

Comment: I'd recommend looking for manufacturer data on the fixture and then contacting the company or searching the interwebs narrowly for the part. In general, I'd expect a cover to be manufacturer specific. In the end, it may be more cost effective to replace the fixture with something that is not missing parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself a lot of trouble, and purchase an entirely new fixture.
If nothing else you'll get more light out of it (note the rather limited reflector at the back of the luminary).

In our throwaway and style driven world, models change and few companies provide spare parts.